# How to add an additional link when clicked in html?

Tags: javascript, php, css, html, php-5.6

The logical error here is when i click the words from the database it displays word in the browser.

```
<select type="true" id="word" name="word" ONCHANGE='this.form.action="english.php?"+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;this.form.submit() ' value="<?php echo $row['word_en']; ?>" multiple size="20">
```

when clicked it only shows the link word:

```
http://localhost/experiment/english.php?Cool
```

I want the link to be like this:

```
http://localhost/experiment/english.php?Cool#navmenu
```

I want to add another links when click.

`#navmenu` is a navigational menu I am aiming that the the browser will stay in that position

Comment: the ? is not the problem.